# Allow a list to hold and compare multiple numeric data types

Tags: c#

I need to determine when `List1` value crossed above `List2` value:

```
Boolean CrossAbove(IList<Decimal> values1, IList<Decimal> values2) {

  return values1[values1.Count - 2] < values2[values2.Count - 2] && values1.Last() > values2.Last();

}
```

How to change `CrossAbove` method to allow, not just `Decimals`, but also `Doubles`, `Ints`, ...

Comment: Your choices - copy & paste then find & replace, or spend a bit of time writing some code generation code in e.g. T4. Second will take a tad longer and you'll end up with the same code, but there's potentially less maintenance work (until the methods, for whatever reason, diverge in implementation)

Comment: I think the most sensible answer will depend on why you want to do this.  I can think of ways to do it immediately, but I wouldn't do them.

Comment: Use an object instead of a decimal.

Comment: ^^ and there's one of them.  It would make much more sense to cast to decimal, rather than use an object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with a generic method constrained to an `IComparable` type argument:

```
bool CrossAbove<T>(IList<T> values1, IList<T> values2) where T : IComparable
{
    return values1[values1.Count - 2].CompareTo(values2[values2.Count - 2]) < 0 && values1.Last().CompareTo(values2.Last()) > 0;
}
```

Value types like `int`, `long`, `float`, `double` etc. implement `IComparable`, so the method can be used with those.

Note that this method should check its inputs, e.g. if there actually are any (non-null) values in the lists before accessing them.

Comment: I was literally writing out the same solution, but you beat me to it :)